# Can qcow2 overlay get committed back into raw backing file?

Tags: libvirt, qemu, qcow2

I am trying to design a system utilizing the btrfs filesystem and libvirt.
btrfs has copy-on-write (COW) already, it's very easy to do snapshots and it's very efficient to transfer the snapshot to a remote as a backup (rsync and other tool are very bad for sparse files).
However, qcow2 is good for transient VM snapshots, we can spin up a VM with temporary overlay then ditch or commit the change back to the base image depending on the outcome.

We want to merge the benefit of both btrfs and qcow2 basically like the following:

- normally VM use raw image in COW FS
- external snapshots with overlay in a tmpfs or NOCOW directory (qcow2 with raw image as a backing file)

My question is: Does this really work? I mean the temporary qcow2 overlay should get committed to a backing file efficiently. Did anyone try this before? How stable is this?